# Do I need to use future perfect tense for expectation?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, tense, expressions

Which one is the correct or I mean a more formal way to tell about an expectation?

> "By the 15 May, we expect everyone to already complete their tasks" or

> "By the 15 May, we expect everyone to have already completed their tasks"

Comment: The first version is syntactically invalid. You *must* use future perfect (the second version) in the cited context. Note that the version as given *(**to have** already done it)* uses ***expect*** in the sense of ***require** [as an obligation]*. The alternative phrasing *we expect everyone **will have** already completed their tasks* doesn't necessarily / normally carry that implication (it usually just means *that's what we think the future situation will be*, regardless of whether that future is something we actually ***want*** to come about).

Comment: Oddly enough, I find that that first one sounds wrong, but "We expect everyone to complete their tasks by May" sounds fine.  (By the way, it is always **May 15th** or **the 15th of May** never *the 15 May*.)

Comment: @stangdon: Good point. It's the presence of ***already*** that makes #1 above invalid. Just as ***I expect to play soon*** is perfectly okay, but ***I expect to already play soon*** is syntactic/semantic garbage.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that most people would accept *I expect to marry by Xmas* as a valid alternative to *I expect to have married by Xmas* (but only the latter can accept inclusion of ***already***). Same applies to *I expect I will marry by Xmas* and *I expect I will have [already] married by Xmas*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adverb "already" is not needed.  The meaning of "already" is given by the present perfect. So you can say:

> By May 15th / By the 15th of May/  we expect everyone to have completed their tasks.

Answer (score -1):

Two things. First, about the date. In American English you would say:

> By May 15,

You might occasionally see:

> By 15 May

But never:

> By the 15 May (wrong)

2. The most common and probably best answer is Yes, use the future perfect:

> ... we expect everyone to have already completed their tasks

However, you might hear:

> ... we expect everyone has already completed their tasks

Implicit in that usage is a supposition that you've arrived in the future and today is May 15. You will hear this quite frequently in spoken American English. It should probably be "On May 15" or "Come May 15," but nonetheless it's very common.

Similarly, you can also say:

> ... we expect that everyone would have already completed their tasks

> ... we expect that everyone already completed their tasks

Comment: I don't think *[by some future date] we expect everyone has already completed their tasks* is syntactically acceptable. That's like saying *I expect you have gone home tomorrow.* Not on.

Comment: "By May 15, we expect that everyone has already completed their tasks..." You will absolutely hear this spoken in American English. While it might not be totally right, it's actually very common.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I qualified my assertion with ***I don't think** [it's acceptable]*. Of course, if I thought everyone else would agree with me, *I wouldn't **of** included that "hedge".* And as I'm sure you know, *most people wouldn't think my "**of**" there was "acceptable"* - despite the fact that an awful lot of people say, "think", and even *write* it like that! :)